# How value from different class/form can be changed without ByRef

Tags: vb.net

Let's assume following example below:

When I call Form2 from Form1 and pass _name of Form1 value. When I show Form1's _name = Alex? I didn't change pname in Form2 and constructor doesn't contains ByRef.

Example code:

```
Public Form1
    Public _name as String

    Sub New
        _name = "John"
        Dim bla as New Form2(_name)
        'now _name=Alex !!
    End Sub
End Class

Public Form2
    Property _name2 as String

    Sub New(pname as String)    'no ByVal !!
           _name2 = pname       'even if would be ByVal no pname changed !
           _name2 = "Alex"
    End Sub
End Class
```

Why is that happening?

Comment: Your code is essentially ignoring the parameter passed

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: If you want Form2 to be able to change the `_name` property value of Form1, it needs a reference to the form object, not just the *value* of a property.  Really bad names, by the way.  Many, many NET things have a Name property - but they are all `Name` not `Name1358` or `_name127`

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Shared in variable _name:

   ```
   Class Form1


       Public Shared _name As String

       Public Sub New()
           _name = "John"
       End Sub

       Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

           ' Message "John"
           MessageBox.Show(_name)

           Dim bla As New Form2()
           bla.Show()

           ' Message "Alex"
           MessageBox.Show(_name)

       End Sub

   End Class


   Public Class Form2

       Property _name2 As String

       Sub New()

           _name2 = "Alex"
           Form1._name = _name2

       End Sub

       Private Sub Form2_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

           ' message Alex
           MessageBox.Show(_name2)

           ' message Alex
           MessageBox.Show(Form1._name)

       End Sub
   End Class
   ```

Or

2. When the modifier is not entered in the signature of a constructor (method), the default is byVal. If you want to change the value of the variable in form2 you must inform byref in the form2 constructor signature:
   Sub New (byref _name as String)

Answer (score 0):

To change the underlying value of an argument you **must** use the [ByRef](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c84t73c2.aspx) `modifer`:

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure can change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

This differs slightly from [ByVal](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h2b185t2.aspx):

> Specifies that an argument is passed in such a way that the called procedure or property cannot change the value of a variable underlying the argument in the calling code.

By not specifying a `modifier` in `VB.NET` the compiler by default will use `ByVal`.

> It would be good to note here that although `VB.NET` uses `ByVal` by default if not specified, `VBA` does not and instead by default uses `ByRef`. Beware of this should you ever port code from one to the other.

Furthermore you are changing `name2` when instead you should be changing `pname` *if* you want to change the underlying value.

Have a look at the following code based on your example:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private _name As String

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

        _name = "John"

        Dim bla As New Form2(_name)
        bla.Show()

        Debug.WriteLine(_name)

    End Sub

End Class

Public Class Form2

    Private Property _name2 As String

    Public Sub New(ByRef pname As String)

        InitializeComponent()

        _name2 = pname
        pname = "Alex"

    End Sub

End Class
```

Before passing the value to `Form2` the name is "John":

[image]

At this point I am changing the value of `pname` to "Alex":

[image]

> Note that although I have changed the value of `pname` To "Alex", `_name2` is still set to "John".

Notice how the value of `_name` changes to "Alex" because of the change made to `pname`:

[image]

I'm not sure what it is you're trying to achieve here but hopefully this example gives you a better understanding. The alternative way would be to use a shared variable as explained in the other answer.